# Graph Api : How to check if a user is using my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way in GraphApi to check if a user is using my application?

With FQL I can do this:

```
/fql?q=select+uid+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+uid=123456789
```

Also, FQL sintax can have a list of users ids. Like

```
/fql?q=select+uid+FROM+user+WHERE+is_app_user+AND+uid=123456789+OR+uid=12398766
```

I am searching to replace FQL with a GraphAPI sintax that can do the same thing. I am afraid that the only solution I have is the fields=installed option, but it would not be the same output like FQL.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging on the internet, I found the equivalent of the FQL sintax that can take in input a list of user ids:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=id1,id2,id3&fields=installed
```

The response looks something like this:

```
{
  "id1": {
   "installed": false, 
   "id": "id1"
  }, 
  "id2": {
   "installed": true, 
   "id": "id2"
  }
}
```